# Excel COUNTIFS Exclusions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I currently have this formula:

```
=COUNTIFS('ACAS Vuln Data'!B$1:B$1048575, "*Windows 10*", 'ACAS Vuln Data'!E$1:E$1048575, "Critical")
+ COUNTIFS('ACAS Vuln Data'!B$1:B$1048575, "*Windows 8*", 'ACAS Vuln Data'!E$1:E$1048575, "Critical") 
+ COUNTIFS('ACAS Vuln Data'!B$1:B$1048575, "*Windows 7*", 'ACAS Vuln Data'!E$1:E$1048575, "Critical") 
+ COUNTIFS('ACAS Vuln Data'!B$1:B$1048575, "*Windows Vista*", 'ACAS Vuln Data'!E$1:E$1048575, "Critical")
```

It works as expected with the exception if I have a single cell that contains values "Windows 8, Windows 10, and Windows Vista, it counts them all.  I want the formula to only count the individual cell versus counting all of the values in the individual cell.

Is there any type of exclude language I could add to my formula so it doesn't count the multiple values in the individual cell?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should just change your ranges to `B:B` instead of `B$1:B$1048575` as they are the same range. (Same for your `E` column criteria)

Comment: @urdearboy the problem in this case with the `-COUNTIFS()` you will need to subtract every possible combination.  So you would need 64 subtraction COUNTIFS().  It would be better to write vba, minus that, limit the referenced ranges and use SUMPRODUCT.

Comment: @Scott Craner thanks for the input!  I will have to do some research on SUMPRODUCT.  I don't have the slightest experience in vba so that will be a challenge.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single `countifs` call with multiple criteria:

```
=COUNTIFS('ACAS Vuln Data'!B$1:B$1048575, {"*Windows 10*", "*Windows 8*", "*Windows 7*", "*Windows Vista*"'}, ACAS Vuln Data'!E$1:E$1048575, "Critical")
```

Comment: 1. This will need to be wrapped in `SUM(...)` 2. It will have the same problem as the OP's formula in that it will count rows that have `Windows 8, Windows 10, and Windows Vista` in the same cell as 3 not 1 as the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

To use SUMPRODUCT one will need to limit the referenced range to that of the data set to avoid extraneous calculations.  Then check if the return of the SEARCH is greater than 0 and Column E is critical.  This will then return `1` or `0` to the SUMPRODUCT.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Windows 10",'ACAS Vuln Data'!B$1:B$1048)))
            +(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Windows 8",'ACAS Vuln Data'!B$1:B$1048)))
            +(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Windows 7",'ACAS Vuln Data'!B$1:B$1048)))
            +(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Windows Vista",'ACAS Vuln Data'!B$1:B$1048)))>0)
            *('ACAS Vuln Data'!E$1:E$1048 = "Critical"))
```

Comment: I will definitely try this thanks.  I tried the previous post from @Mureinik but it will count records that contain windows 10 and combined values in a single cell, no others.

Comment: I'm getting a #Name?  from the code you submitted.  I tried to take screenshots but I don't see an option to upload them here.